# Are you supposed to use multiple scheduler theads?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, scheduling

There is very little in the way of advice or information on MS's User Mode Scheduling API, and one thing in particular is confusing me. Are you supposed to create multiple scheduler threads? If so why? My intuition is that you would create one scheduling thread that would distribute the worker threads to all the logical cores based on program defined logic, effectively creating cooperative scheduling.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/user-mode-scheduling) seems to be quite explicit on this topic: *"Create one UMS scheduler thread for each processor on which the application will run UMS worker threads."*

Comment: @IInspectable Is it possible that means processor and not core? Also, this doesn't answer WHY this is necessary

Answer (score 0):

*[To take advantage of UMS, an application must implement a scheduler component that manages the application's UMS threads and determines when they should run.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/user-mode-scheduling)*
[Multiple Processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multiple-processors) and [NUMA Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/numa-support) imply only one scheduler needed.

Comment: I believe those sections refer to the system scheduler and not the user mode scheduler

Comment: Any differences? Don't they do the same job?

Comment: No, one is customizable. They are very different